# Why does Mongodb create an array with an ObjectsId instead of a simple array of objects?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I had a document that has an array of Objects. When I create a new document the array of Objects are created with ObjectsId.

Does this is normal?
Do I need to specify something to avoid this?.

mongoose options:

```
mongoose.connect(config.mongoUrl, {
useNewUrlParser: true,
useCreateIndex: false,
useUnifiedTopology: true,
useFindAndModify: false,
```

Schema:

```
...    
tags: [{
        name: { type: String },
        experience: { type: Number },
      }],
```

graphql typdefs:

```
type _tag {
    name: String
    experience: Int
  }
...

type Freelance implements IObjetoWerk {
...
    tags: [_tag]
...
}
```

graphql Resolver:

```
`...
const newObjetoWerk = new werkModels.ObjetoWerk(input);
await newObjetoWerk.save();
console.log(newObjetoWerk);
return newObjetoWerk;
...`
```

graphiQL query variable:

```
...
"tags": [
  {
    "name": "Clown",
    "experience": 2
  }
],
```

Result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGoEO.png)

Comment: id or _id (or any unique key) is required by cache in graphql client like apollo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to remove the ObjectId added on the subdocument, so you should specify that on the schema definition

```js
...
tags: [{
        _id: false,
        name: { type: String },
        experience: { type: Number },
}],
...
```

Anything else let me know.